# regarding analyzing unique values of image array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, python-imaging-library

There is the following function to read image, I add several lines to re-output the image, and to output the different pixel values of the image array. The image looks like this. However the 
    **a,indices =np.unique(img,return_index=True)**

gives

**a  [0 1]**

**indices  [0  879385]**

It seems that the image array has two unique values, [0 1], which makes sense, but what does indices indicate?

```
def _get_image_data_pil(image_id, image_type, return_exif_md=False, return_shape_only=False):
    fname = get_filename(image_id, image_type)
    try:
        img_pil = Image.open(fname)
    except Exception as e:
        assert False, "Failed to read image : %s, %s. Error message: %s" % (image_id, image_type, e)

    if return_shape_only:
        return img_pil.size[::-1] + (len(img_pil.getbands()),)
    # -----
    # this is what I adde
    # -----

    img = np.asarray(img_pil)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
    a,indices =np.unique(img,return_index=True)
    print('a ',a)
    print('indices ',indices)

    assert isinstance(img, np.ndarray), "Open image is not an ndarray. Image id/type : %s, %s" % (image_id, image_type)
    if not return_exif_md:
        return img
    else:
        return img, img_pil._getexif()
```

[image]

Comment: Probably the index to the first pixel of each value.

Answer (score 1):

The indices give the first occurrences of unique values in the *flattened* input array.  To convert those indices to 2-d indices into the input, you can use `np.unravel_index`.

For example, suppose the shape of `img` is (1000, 1600):

```
In [110]: shape = (1000, 1600)

In [111]: indices = [0, 879385]

In [112]: np.unravel_index(indices, shape)
Out[112]: (array([  0, 549]), array([  0, 985]))
```

`np.unravel_indices` returned two arrays, one for each dimension.  That is, the first array holds the indices of the first dimension (i.e. the rows) and the second holds the indices of the second dimension (i.e. the columns).  To put these into an array of coordinates, you can use `np.column_stack`:

```
In [113]: np.column_stack(np.unravel_index(indices, shape))
Out[113]: 
array([[  0,   0],
       [549, 985]])
```